# How to run a SQL script at every MySQL initialization?

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, mariadb, docker-entrypoint

I would like to like to run a SQL script at MySQL initialization. This script has basically some UPDATE commands and has be run at each initialization. Basically, the ideia is to update Root and User passwords at each initialization, with vault credentials that are obtained at each database startup. The MySQL database is being deployed inside a Docker container.

In this scenario, is there a way to preset a SQL script that can be run at every database initialization inside a Docker container? If so, please give us an example of how to do implement that. I do use docker-entrypoint.sh and foreground.sh for some customizations at such container.

Comment: which docker image do you use?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch, I am using a MariaDB 10.3.15, but extended. In other words, I have the Dockerfike of such image, so that I can make changes on it, as needed. For instance, I can manipulate its Dockerfile, docker-entrypoint.sh and I did create a foreground.sh with SQL script to be run at initialization. But challenge is exactly make that script runs after MariaDB is initialized.

Comment: It sounds like you already know about the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mechanism, then?

Comment: @David Maze, I still never tried the use of directory `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, but I just seek about it and found that it is used to run SQL scripts just before the service initialization. Nevertheless, in my scenario, I do need to run the SQL script just after the initialization.

Answer (score 3):

`mysqld` accepts a parameter that specifies initialization scripts and you can use that.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.1
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/script/init.sql
    command: "--init-file /script/init.sql"
```

**init.sql**

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("mihai") WHERE USER="root";
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin="mysql_native_password";
```

**.env**

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
```

Run the container and test it:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exec db mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -pmihai
select plugin from mysql.user where USER='root';
```

You can see that the plugin has also been updated so the scripts both worked.

You can remove the command and test with the original password as well. Make sure to remove the volumes between runs.

Comment: _**Using "--init-file /new_vault.sql"**_

_**Output Errors**_
`Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
Added new Master_info '' to hash table
[Warning] 'user' entry 'root@8d1a40106f9f' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
[Warning] 'user' entry '@8d1a40106f9f' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
[Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@8d1a40106f9f' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysqld: ready for connections.
MySQL init process in progress.
MySQL init process failed.`

Comment: You should see a line mentioning that it is running the init script. Since you don't it means that you still have old volumes present. O guarantee this procedure works because I tested it